# Counting Characters in a Text File

Tags: java

Hey guys i'm trying to write a code that will count the characters in a text file.

ex : `AAABBbbcC`

```
3A 2B 2b 1c 2C
```

but i don't know how to count the characters like `(AAA)` if they are not separated.

i'm trying this but it doesn't work like a recursion

```
String s = "aasjkkk";

int count1 = 0;

int count2 = 0;

char karakter1 = 0;

char karakter2 = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){

    if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1)) {

        karakter1 = s.charAt(i);
        count1 += 1;

        System.out.print(count1 + " " + karakter1 + " ");

    }
    else if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i+1)) {

        karakter1 = s.charAt(i);

            karakter1 = 1;

            karakter2 = s.charAt(i+1);

            karakter2 = 1;

            System.out.print(count1 + " " + karakter1 + " " + count2 + " " + karakter2 + " ");
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not how StackOverflow works. You must show effort in researching, posting the code you have tried, explaining why it's not working, and asking an specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like a homework, I can suggest a way for you to do this:

1. Create a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
2. Loop from the beginning to the end of the file. If you have a new character, then set a new key to the HashMap with 1 as the value; if not, just plus one to the current value of the old character

Have fun !!

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you ***should*** and **must** show what you've tried before.

I think that you could have already thought about taking the String into a `char` array, iterating, etc...

Well, @bubuzz advise is a good one, here it comes an implementation:

public class ClasesObjetos {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "This is a single String";

    HashMap<Character, Integer> m = new HashMap();

    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {

        if (!c.equals(" ")) {

            if (m.get(c) == null )
                m.put(c, 1);

            else {
                int i = (int) m.get(c) + 1;
                m.put(c, i);
            }

        }
    }

    for (Character c : m.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(c + " ---> " + m.get(c));
    }

}
```

}

Try it out you'll see it ignores spaces. It will count any symbols though, you should you add up `if` checks.